# Python try/except depending on variable

Tags: python, if-statement, error-handling, try-except

i need continue in program after except when variable is True but when variable is False need exit program.
I think there will be if else but I'm not sure how to use it.

for examlpe:

```
var = True

try:
    print 2/0
except:
    exit(1)

... continue executing
```

---

```
var = False

try:
    print 2/0
except:
    exit(1)

... exit
```

Thanks for comments.

Comment: Wrap the exit in an if?

Answer (score 1):

This ought to do the trick, by the way you should probably use raise.

```
var = True

try:
    print 2/0
except:
    if not var:
        # I recommend using raise, as it would show you the error
        exit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, and when is there more than one except and I do not write 'if' under every except ?

Comment: if its possible,wrap the whole thing block of code with try/except, instead of every line.
It would really help to see some part of the code as this style of programming is not the best practice.
You could encapsulate the logic inside a function and then call it with map() and list of arguments.

Comment: Yes it is a function and 'var' is one of args, see below

Answer (score 1):

If you have a number of `except` groups which will need to use the var try this

Note that you can expand myexcept using decorators or closures in order to set up additional processing within the exception as well. Since a function is an object, you can use a different specialfunc() for every `except:` that you write. You can set up the myexcept to handle calls to specialfunc() with arguments as well using the variable arguments process as shown below

```
def specialfunc1():
     # put the special function code here

def specialfunc2(arg1):
    # put the processing here

def specialfunc3(arg1, arg2):
    # put the processing here

def myexcept(var, e, specialfunc, *args)
    print 'Exception caught for ', e
    if var:
        specialfunc(*args)
    else:
        raise # This raises the current exception to force an exit

try:
    # code you are testing
    2/0
except Error1, e:
    myexcept(var, e, specialfunc1)
except Error2, e:
    myexcept(var, e, specialfunc2(arg1))
except Error3, e:
    myexcept(var, e, specialfunc3(arg1, arg2))
except: # this default forces the regular exception handler

# remaining code
```